# Dynamically slice a string using a variable

Tags: python, list, variables, dynamic, slice

I am trying to slice a string and insert the components into a list (or index, or set, or anything), then compare them, such that

Input:

```
abba
```

Output:

```
['ab', 'ba']
```

Given a variable length of the input.

So if I slice a string

```
word = raw_input("Input word"
slicelength = len(word)/2
longword[:slicelength]
```

such that

```
    list = [longwordleftslice]
    list2 = [longwordrightslice]

    list2 = list2[::-1 ] ## reverse slice
    listoverall = list + list2
```

However, the built-in slice command `[:i]` specifies that `i` be an integer.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do that..

```
word = "spamspamspam"
first_half = word[:len(word)//2]
second_half = word[len(word)//2:]
```

For any string `s` and any integer `i`, `s == s[:i] + [:i]` is invariant.  Note that if `len(word)` is odd, you will get one more character in the second "half" than the first.

If you are using python 3, use `input` as opposed to `raw_input`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using Python 3. Use `//` instead of `/`. In Python 3, `/` always returns a `float`, which lists don't like. `//` returns an int, truncating everything past the decimal point.

Then all you have to do is slice before and after the midpoint.

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> midpoint = len(a) // 2
>>> a[:midpoint]
[0, 1]
>>> a[midpoint:]
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: this was my first guess too, but then they wouldn't be using `raw_input` right.. ?

Comment: @wim, that's true. But fortunately `//` works in either case. In any case, I can't imagine a reason why the OP would be getting a `TypeError` from the above code, other than true division.